# firefox notificationclick handler not working as espected (open browser with path)

Tags: javascript, web, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-worker

I'm using a service worker to show notifications when a push message is received. The message contains a path where the event that triggered the notification happened.

I want to use that path to open a browser window over there.

How ever my code does not work and there are some inconsistencies between chrome and firefox.

Here is the code (updated)

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
  const { title, options } = event.data.json();
  self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  event.notification.close();
  const { path } = event.notification.data;
  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: "window",
      })
      .then((clientList) => {
        if (clientList.length)
          return clientList[0].navigate(path)
            .then(client => client.focus());

        if (clients.openWindow)
          return clients.openWindow(self.location.origin + path)
            .then(client => client.focus());
      })
  );
});
```

options = { data: { path: '/path/where/notification/triggered' } }

UPDATE: the options payload was wrong. Now chrome works in all cases but firefox still is unable to open a window when the browser is closed, yet it navigates well when there's an opened window.

thx in advance

Comment: by the way, all examples of handling `push` event seem to use `event.waitUntil` - perhaps that's the issue - as for `clients` - your code seems very simple compared to [this example](https://github.com/mdn/serviceworker-cookbook/blob/master/push-clients/README.md)

Comment: push handler does it well in all browsers

Comment: it does work on firefox nightly so I believe that the behavior is okay